# Laravel ,in bladeview count with groupBy

Tags: laravel, group-by, laravel-blade

I have this in my blade

```
{{$apartment -> messages() -> count()}}
```

This gives me back the total of messages relating to an apartment. However, I would like the count to be differentiated according to the "created_at", for example with groupBy and then return the total for each date. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do this by Laravel [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries) either this way:

```php
$apartment->messages()
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as count, date(created_at) as created_date')
    ->groupBy('created_date')
    ->get()
```

Or:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$apartment->messages()
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as count')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(created_at)'))
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but it should be work:

```
$aGroupedMessages = $apartment->messages()->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
})

foreach ($aGroupedMessages as $sDate => $aMessages) {
    echo $sDate . " => " . count($aMessages); 
}
```

$apartment->messages() are collections.
look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby